# Proving all divisors of $n$ are congruent to $1$ $\pmod p$ with $p$ a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a way to prove that ALL divisors of $n$ are congruent to $1$ $\pmod p$ without factoring $n$ and $n-1$ $|$ $p$ with $p$ prime.

One way would be to see if $n$ $|$ $2^p-1$ with $p$ prime. Then the following is a proof that all integers $q$ $|$ $n$, $q-1$ $|$ $p$. Is there a way to do this for any ordinary $n$. This should work for all prime numbers, but this is not a proof $n$ is prime.

For an example, what would be the steps to showing all divisors $q$ of $402107460361$, $q-1$ $|$ $47$ (this includes $1$ as a divisor since $0$ is a multiple of any number.) **without** factoring $402107460361$. I would try using degree polynomials of $x^{47}$ but I am not sure where to go from there. Thanks.

Comment: $n\equiv1\pmod{p}$ means $p|(n-1)$. Do you mean to write $p|(n-1)$ instead of $n-1|p$?

Comment: Let $n=15$.  $3 \times 5=15$.  $7$ divides $n-1=14$ but neither $3$ nor $5$ are $1\pmod 7$.

Comment: Also:  just to reinforce the comment of @stewbasic ...if you want to say that "$p$ divides $m$" the notation is $p\,|\,m$.

Comment: @lulu A quick compositeness test: $p$ $|$ $n-1$, all factors of $n$ are not $1$ $\pmod p$, $n$ is composite. However try not to factor $n$ first.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @lulu try my example with $n$ $=$ $402107460361$. $47$ $|$ $n-1$ so I am looking for a quick test to prove or disprove the claim that all divisors of $n$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {47}$. If this is disproved without factoring $n$, then $n$ is obviously composite. If this is proven, then that does not imply $n$ is prime (or composite).